# Jquery child div selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using switchy http://lou.github.io/switchy/ and it uses animate-color.js

I have more than one, unlike their page, everytime one gets toogle all of them turn green, how can I prevent this so one gets toogle only

```
$(function () {
    $('.binary').switchy();
    $('.binary').on('change', function () {
        // Animate Switchy Bar background color 7cb15b
        var bgColor = '#ebebeb';
        if ($(this).val() == '1') {
            bgColor = '#7cb15b';
        } else if ($(this).val() == '0;') {
            bgColor = '#ebebeb';
        }
        $('.switchy-bar').animate({
            backgroundColor: bgColor
        });
        // Display action in console
        var log = 'Selected value is "' + $(this).val() + '"';
        $('#console').html(log).hide().fadeIn();
    });
});
```

You can see what I mean here www.niors.com

Comment: How does the `.switchy-bar` element relate to the `.binary` element? Could you please show your HTML

Comment: any HTML markup you like to share?

Comment: @user2726228 any why we bother to view it there ? If you cannot share it for your own sake...

Comment: Sorry I was on phone when I asked the question and couldn't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
$('.switchy-bar').animate({
    backgroundColor: bgColor
});
```

you get ALL `switchy-bar` from document. So you need to find context you need, i.a. this way:

```
$(this).parent().find('.switchy-bar').animate({
    backgroundColor: bgColor
});
```

`#(this)` -> select

`$(this).parent()` -> wrapper (`.field`)

and then search for switchy bar for changed select.
Of course, for better performance and readibility it'd be great to cache `$(this)` in some variable at the beginning of callback function.

Something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.binary').switchy();
    $('.binary').on('change', function () {
        var $select = $(this);
        var selectedValue = $select.val();

        // Animate Switchy Bar background color 7cb15b
        var bgColor = {
            '0': '#ebebeb',
            '1': '#7cb15b'
        };

        $select.parent().find('.switchy-bar').animate({
            backgroundColor: bgColor[ selectedValue ]
        });

        // Display action in console
        var log = 'Selected value is "' + selectedValue + '"';
        $('#console').html(log).hide().fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$('.switchy-bar').animate({
    backgroundColor: bgColor
});
```

to

```
$(this).parent().find('.switchy-bar').animate({
    backgroundColor: bgColor
});
```

the idea is to just change one switchy-bar which is related to element you are clicking or selecting for...